# Collection View Cell subview frame not available until cell is reused

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have collection view cells that contain a subview of which I am trying to get the frame of in relation to the superview.

So far, I've managed to successfully get the frame of the subview, however for the first x amount of *visible* cells, the returned frame is always (0,0,0,0).

After I scroll them out of view and scroll back to those x cells, the returned frame is fine and the frames for the subviews are computed properly.

Any thoughts?

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow

    let selectedCell = self.collectionView(self.cellCollectionView, cellForItemAt: indexPath) as! postCell

    let photoItem = selectedCell.photo
    let photoItemPosition = photoItem.frame

    let convertedFrame = selectedCell.convert(photoItemPosition, to: window)

    print(photoItemPosition)
    print(convertedFrame)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to update the frame of `photo` instance in `layoutSubviews`.
Override the `layoutSubviews` in your collectionView cell class

```
override func layoutSubviews ()
{
    super.layoutSubviews()
    //Set the self.photo frame 
}
```